# Determine if the compiler is little or big endian in C

Tags: c, endianness

Could anyone tell me how this program can determine if the compiler is little or big endian.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main(void) {
    union {
       long lungo;
       char ch[sizeof(long)];
    } unione;
    unione.lungo = 1;
    if (unione.ch[sizeof(long)-1] == 0)
       printf("little endian\n");
    else
       printf("big endian\n");
    return (0);
}
```

Especially I didn't understand what this part of program do:

```
union {
       long lungo;
       char ch[sizeof(long)];
    } unione;
```

Thanks

Comment: First of all compiler is not big or little endian, architecture is.. and what you are doing is UB, you are writing lungo, but reading ch.

Comment: @SandBag_1996: Aliasing to/from `char` by a union is legal.

Comment: Please use a C book to learn what a `union` is. That is your major problem.

Comment: "little or big endian"` are 2 of the common endians - others exist, though tend to be rare.

Comment: @Olaf I read the standard again and you are right, type punning is allowed in C, but not C++. I guess I confused the two. Thanks for correcting that

Comment: @SandBag_1996: Another reason both are **different** languages.

Comment: @@SandBag_1996  Endian-ness is controlled by the compiler, which obliviously is strongly influenced by the underlying hardware.  In situations where the hardware works both ways or is not applicable (e.g. endian of FP on a machine without a FP instructions, or 8-bit processor), it is entirely up to the compiler.

Comment: @chux: A big-endian compiler may very well generate code for a little endian target. This is typical for cross-compilers. The endianess of the compiler does not matter for the translated program code, but that of the target. So he is quite correct (maybe one of us missunderstood what he meant?).

Comment: @Rad Lexus [Jeopardy](https://www.jeopardy.com) gives answers, not questions.  IOWs big endian questions.

Comment: @chux I understand, but if you read OP's question title, OP states that he wants to know if the compiler is big endian or little endian, which does not make sense to me. I meant to say the program code generated, the endianness of which, even though enforced by compiler, is dependent on the target.

Comment: Ok, I was right about gcc: `__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__` etc are defined macros. Not sure if they are available in strict compliance mode, though. But they are certainly a better way if you are allowed to use them. It is easy try using them in the first place and use a fallback solution if they are not available. Evaluating the endianess at run-time is very use-less anyway.

Comment: Note: `sys/types.h` is not a standard C header. It is also not used in the code shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the members of a union occupy the same memory, such that they are overlaid on each other; writing to one member of a union updates *all* members of the union.

You've set up `unione` to store 2 members; `lungo` is a `long`, and `ch` is an array of `char` sized to hold `sizeof long` bytes (4 or 8 bytes, depending on your system; for this discussion, we'll assume 4 bytes).  Both of these members are overlaid on top of each other (they occupy the same 4 bytes of memory).

Remember that on a big-endian system, the *most significant* byte of a multi-byte type will be stored at address A and the *least significant* byte will be stored at address A+3.  On a little-endian system, that order is reversed; the least significant byte will be stored at address A and the most significant byte will be stored at address A+3:

```
   BE:  A     A+1   A+2   A+3     where A is arbitrary address
        ----  ----  ----  ----
lungo:  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x01
        ----  ----  ----  ----
   LE:  A+3   A+2   A+1   A
```

Arrays, on the other hand, are always stored such that `a[0]` is stored at address A, `a[1]` is stored at A+1, etc.  So if we look at `ch` in relation to `lungo` on both big- and little-endian systems, we see the following:

```
   BE: ch[0]  ch[1]  ch[2]  ch[3]
       -----  -----  -----  -----
lungo: 0x00   0x00   0x00   0x01
       -----  -----  -----  -----
   LE: ch[3]  ch[2]  ch[1]  ch[0]
```

Thus, on a little-endian system, `ch[0]` corresponds to the least significant byte of `lungo`, which contains the value `0x01`.  On a big-endian system, `ch[0]` corresponds to the most significant byte of `lungo`, which contains the value `0x00`.

This is a common trick to determine endianness, but strictly speaking the behavior is undefined; you're not supposed to write to one member of a union and read from a different member.  This technique "works" because any multi-byte type can be mapped cleanly onto an array of `char` or `unsigned char`, but it's not something that can be cleanly applied between two multi-byte types in general.

There's no 100% portable, standard-compliant way to determine the endianness of a system, at least none that I know of.  All the ones I know involve tricks like this or some kind of type punning, like

```
long l = 0x00010203;
char *c = (char *) &l; 
if ( c[0] == 0x03 )
  // little-endian
else if ( c[0] == 0x00 )
  // big-endian
else 
  // something else
```

Again, this isn't good practice and is probably undefined, but it "works" for most cases.

Big- and little-endianness aren't the only possible orderings, and more than one ordering is possible on a single system.  VAXen were normally little-endian except for 32-bit floats, which were "middle-endian" and laid out as 2301.

Comment: As I recall, writing to one `union` member and reading from a field (same size) of `unsigned char []` is not undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
union {
       long lungo;
       char ch[sizeof(long)];
    } unione;
```

This is a *union*. Its members occupy *the same memory area*. It is a common trick to write to one member (integer in this case)...

```
unione.lungo = 1;
```

...and then read back through the other (usually a char array)...

```
if (unione.ch[sizeof(long)-1] == 0)
```

...to get at the byte-wise representation of the former type. (In this case, the "first" byte of the integer, to determine if the `1` stored in the integer shows up in it (which would make this a little-endian platform), or not (which would make it a big-endian platform). Note @chux comment -- other forms of endianess *do* exist, although they are very rare.

Appendix J.1 specifies "the value of a union member other than the last one stored into" as **unspecified**.

Appendix J.3.13 specifies "the number, order, and encoding of bytes in any object (when not explicitly specified in this International Standard)" as **implementation-defined**.

Section 6.2.6 ("Representation of types") specifies that "certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored
value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is **undefined**."

So, while not Undefined Behaviour, this construct is... let's say, walking close to the sideline. ;-)

Comment: That is legal, but bad practice, as it relies on too many implementation-specific variables. There are standard compliant, thus portable ways to (de)serialise/marshall standard types.

Answer (score 0):

`#define IS_BIG_ENDIAN (!*(unsigned char*)(void*)&(uint16_t){1})` is a nice way to do it if your compiler has `uint16_t`. But there may well be other "endianness" schemes that could give you a false positive. I'm not sure. On that point, I'd welcome a downvote with a counter-example!

Technically the behaviour on using the "union trick" is undefined in C++, although you'll get away with it in C.

The casting through `(void*)` is superfluous in C, but is technically necessary in C++.

Comment: This violates effective type rule, thus invokes UB. The union is perfectly legal in C. Though not a good idea if you just want to marshall objects. I think gcc at least provides macros for this (not sure, though, it might also be the library).

Comment: @Olaf: No macros for this in the standard library, I am afraid. (At least not in C99, I am not yet 100% confident with regards to C11.)

Comment: @Olaf: Can you explain why you think this is UB, with citation to the standard if possible?  In n1548, section 6.5.7 explicitly allows accessing an object of another type through a pointer to a character type.  AFAIK this has always been an exception to type aliasing rules.  (Without this exception, for instance, it would be impossible to implement `memcpy` in a portable fashion.)

Comment: @DevSolar: Sorry I was not clear: I did not mean the C standard library, but glibc or newlib. IIRC, I saw something like that in some gcc projects and I'm sure it was from the toolchain, not application code. But it is too long ago and that kind of serialisation is just bad practice now imo.

Comment: @NateEldredge: n1548 is an outdated draft, so I will not even think about it. Use n1570 only (this is technically identical to the final standard). Re the point: Sorry, I somehow missinterpreted somethin into this. It is just the intermediate cast to `void *` which is unnecessary. I'll dummy-edit the question and remove the DV. Ashes on my head.

Comment: Sorry, I had to dummy-edit to remove a dummy DV;-) The intermediate cast to `void *` is not required in C at least (not sure about C++). No need to DV for that, but yes, there are other variants like half-word (16bit in 32 bits) endianess and other stuff (bit-endianess).

Comment: @Olaf: Thanks.  The text in n1570 is the same.  Also, I should not have said "6.5.7" but rather "6.5 paragraph 7".

Comment: @Olaf: you're correct about the superfluity of the (void*) cast in C.

Comment: @NateEldredge: This one I had accepted without reference even. I even don't know why I thought it was wrong.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Just out of curiosity: How is it in C++? I think, it is the same, but I'd appreciate if you correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I answered a question on exactly thos some time ago. And the OP had even included the standard refs in the question! I'll try to find it when I'm next in the office.